# Writing result page for a query in MongoDB, NodeJS and Express using Ajax to update resutls

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

Hello I am writing a search form, which I validate using boostrapvalitator, once the form is validated I send the query to the server using Ajax, the response comes back from the server and I'm re writing part of the search screen with the response using Ajax and javascritp. The issue that I have is that I'm using express-paginate in the router so it limitates the number of records sent back to the client, and when I want to show more of the results, I'm not sure how to refresh the part of the results to get the second bunch of records. 
My question is how do you structure this architecture using ajax, mongodb, express-paginate, and express? 
Thanks

Comment: The "issue" seems to be a lack of reading the documentation. `Model.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, results, itemCount)`. Not to hard for most of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every paged response you should return the maximum no. of search results found. Then from client side you can determine which page you should request and request the server with that page number and maximum number of results per page.Use skip and limit in DB query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it was an issue with the way I was fetching the second data set, I had to use another Ajax call to get the router that originated the first response, and the same function to update the page.